# Proof verification: product and sum of two natural numbers are consecutive natural numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I just wanted to check if this is a valid proof of the statement given in the question

> Are there infinitely many pairs $(m,n)$ with $m,n \in \Bbb N$ such that $m+n = k$ and $mn = k+1$ where $k \in \Bbb N$?

Proof: Clearly $(2,3)$ is a solution since $2 + 3 = 5$ and $2\cdot 3 = 6$. Suppose $(m,n)$ is a solution. Then $$mn - (m+n) = 1$$

from which we conclude that

$$m = \frac{n + 1}{n-1}$$

and so $(m,n)$ is a solution iff $(n-1) \vert (n+1)$, or equivalently, if $n + 1 \equiv 0 \mod {n-1}$. This is equivalent to the condition that $n \equiv n -2 \mod{n-1}$. Partitioning the natural numbers into even and odd integers, we find that the only time that this happens is when $n = 2$ or $n = 3$.

Comment: From your title, you may have missed $m=1$ or $n=1$ where "product and sum of two natural numbers are consecutive natural numbers"

Comment: Indeed. The title and the blockquote aren't quite the same, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

Two minor points:

1) When dividing by $n-1$, you should make sure to exclude the case $n = 1$.

2) The equation $n \equiv n-2 \mod n-1$ can be simplified to $-2 \equiv 0 \mod n-1.$ Thus $n-1 \mid -2$, which only leaves $n=2$ and $n=3$. Doing it like this, you don't have to argue with any partitions of natural numbers and the proof gets a little shorter.

Apart from that it looks good.

Comment: That's nicer too. Thanks!

Comment: From $ mn- (m + n) = 1 $ there is a more obvious and short continuation $ (m-1)(n-1) = 2. $

Answer (score 1):

$mn-m-n+1=2$. So $(m-1)(n-1)=2 $ Has very few chioces. Write those two or three explicitly done.

Comment: (+1) This is what came to my mind when I saw this question.

Answer (score 0):

For the $(n-1)|(n+1)$ part, it might be simpler to observe that $$\gcd(n-1,n+1) =\gcd(2,n-1)$$ and therefore any common divisor is at most 2.

Then since $n-1$ is a common divisor, $n-1≤2$.